# Why can't mortise locks be installed upside down?

Tags: doors, lock

I purchased a mortise lock for a gate today and the person at the shop told me to make sure I install it right side up — lock on top and handle on bottom — and that a lot of customers install them upside down then complain that they don't work correctly.

I believe them because this shop existed for the sole purpose of making custom doors and selling parts, but I can't really figure out why and didn't think to ask when I was there (and also I don't have any pressing need to install one with the lock on the bottom).

My question is: Why don't mortise locks work correctly if installed upside down (handle on top, lock on bottom)?

Comment: Lock cylinders generally don't like to be upside down because gravity will drop gunk into the pins and springs. Dunno if this is what they were talking about.

Comment: I do not know but  i would guess that some of the internal parts are assisted by gravity.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate -- probably not the lock cylinder (Europrofile cylinders are installed pin-stacks-down just about everywhere one goes)